# Inserting rows - bulk or row by row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, sql-insert

I am inserting data into a database using millions of insert statements stored in a file. Is it better to insert this row by row or in bulk ? I am not sure what the implications can be. 
Any suggestions on the approach ? Right now, I am executing 50K of these statements at a time.

Comment: Where are you getting the insert statements?  A flat file?  Load the whole file, don't execute millions of insert statements.

Comment: @GoatCO - Its actually inside SSIS, an ETL tool. I want to go for bulk insert. But, others want row by row insert. Bulk inserts are sometimes causing out of memory errors.

Comment: Now that that's been made clear, I'm not entirely familiar with transferring data from inside SSIS to a database, but if there's a batch size option, you should be looking for that and setting it to process several hundred to several thousand records at a shot (depending on what you think your server can handle)

Comment: @user2366842 - yes. but eventually, sql server will be running those statements. So, I need to know whether bulk or row by row is better for sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you're much better off inserting in bulk, provided you know that the inserts won't fail for some reason (i.e. invalid data, etc).  If you're going row by row, what you're doing, is opening the data connection, adding the row, closing the data connection.  Rinse wash, repeat in your case tens of thousands of times (or more?).  It's a huge performance hit as opposed to opening the connection once, dumping all the data at one shot, then closing the connection once.  If your data ISN'T a clean set of data, you might be better off going row by row, as the bulk insert won't fail if you have data to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SSIS, I would suggest a data flow task as another possible avenue.  This will allow you to move data from a flat text file, SQL table or other source and map it into your new table.  Performance, I have found, is always pretty good and I use it regularly.

If your table is not created before the insert, what I do is drag an Execute SQL Task function into my process with the table creation query (CREATE TABLE....etc.) and update the properties on the data flow function to delay validation.

As long as my data structure is consistent, this works.  Here are a couple screenshots.

[image: SSIS Flow]

[image: Validation]

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use the BULK INSERT instead of inserting row by row. The BULK INSERT is the in-process method designed for bringing data from a text file into SQL Server, ant it is the fasted among other approaches described in the [The Data Loading Performance Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) online article

Comment: see the above answer. bulk insert might not be the right choice for every situation.

Answer (score 0):

The other alternative is to use a batch process that uses set-based processing over a smaller set of records (say 5000 at a time) . This can keep the server from getting totally locked up and is faster than one record at a time.